# React Redux & ContextApi - How to pass a prop via context and keeping it "connected"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

Considering the following project setup on a react-redux application that uses context API to avoid prop drilling. The example given is simplified.

### Project Setup

1. React project uses React Redux
2. Uses context API to avoid prop drilling in certain cases.
3. Redux store has a prop `posts` which contains list of posts
4. An action creator `deletePost()`, which deletes a certain post by post id.
5. To avoid prop drilling, both `posts` and `deletePosts()` is added to a context `AppContext` and returned by a hook funciton `useApp()`.
6. `posts` array is passed via contexts so it is not used by `connect()` function. *Important*

### Problem:

When action is dispatched store is updated however Component is not re-rendered (because the prop is not connected?). Of course, if I pass the prop with connect function and drill it down to child rendering works fine.

What is the solution?

#### Example Project

The example project can be found in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-react-redux-qig00?file=/src/App.js). Open up the console and try to click the delete button. You will see no change in the UI while you can see the state is updated in the console.

#### Codes

##### `App.js`

```
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import "./styles.css";
import { AppProvider } from "./context";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Home />
      </div>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

##### `context.js`

```
import { useDispatch, useStore } from "react-redux";
import { useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { deletePost } from "./redux/actions/posts";

export const AppContext = createContext();

export const useApp = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    posts: { items: posts }
  } = useStore().getState();

  const value = {
    // props
    posts,

    // actions
    deletePost,
    dispatch
  };
  return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
```

##### `Home.js`

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Post from "../components/Post";
import { useApp } from "../context";

const Home = () => {
  const { posts } = useApp();
  return (
    <section>
      {posts.map((p) => (
        <Post key={p.id} {...p} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};
/*
const mapProps = ({ posts: { items: posts } }) => {
  return {
    posts
  };
};
*/
export default connect()(Home);
```

##### `Post.js`

```
import { useApp } from "../context";

const Post = ({ title, content, id }) => {
  const { deletePost, dispatch } = useApp();
  
  const onDeleteClick = () => {
    console.log("delete it", id);
    dispatch(deletePost(id));
  };

  return (
    <article>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{content}</p>
      <div className="toolbar">
        <button onClick={onDeleteClick}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `useSelector()` instead of `useState()`. Example codepen is fixed.

#### Change from:

```
const { posts: { items: posts } } = useStore().getState();
```

#### Change to:

```
const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts.items);
```

`useStore()` value is only received when component is first mounted. While `useSlector()` will get value when value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the connect higher order component method properly . Try using it like this so your component will get the states and the function of your redux store :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { callAction } from '../redux/actions.js';

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div> {JSON.stringify(props)} </div>
  )
}

const mapState = (state) => {
  name : state.name // name is in intialState
}

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => {
  callAction : () => dispatch(callAction()) // callAction is a redux action 
  //and should be imported in the component also
}

export default connect(mapState , mapDispatch)(Home);
```

You can access the states and the actions from your redux store via component props.

Comment: So how would you avoid prop drilling this way?

Comment: @Sisir what do you mean ?